# React Iconify set color based on theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, icons

I've a NextJS app built with tailwind. I'm using React Iconify icons, the application supports dark mode based on the system theme using tailwind.config.js

```
darkMode: "class",
```

I'm trying to set the icon color based on the current theme, but my function always returns true. This is my function

```
function checkTheme() {
    return (
      typeof window !== "undefined" &&
      window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")
    );
  }
```

Here's where I'm using it to set the Icon color

```
          <Icon
            className="cursor-pointer"
            icon="entypo-social:linkedin-with-circle"
            width={24}
            color={checkTheme() ? "white" : "black"}
            height={24}
            onClick={() =>
              openInNewTab("https://www.linkedin.com/")
            }
          />
```

Comment: You forgot to add `.matches` when matching the media query, e.g. `window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/matches.

Comment: Hi thanks! it's solved. You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Even if you don't set the "color" prop on the Iconify icon, it will inherit the "text color" attribute from the parent div element. So, if you have something like this, the icon's color would be updated as needed.

```<div className="text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900>
  <Icon ..../>
</div>```